# ngrx effects called multiple times after it return the value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

ngrx effects called multiple times after it return the value.

```
loadMovies$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(counterActions.CounterActionTypes.IncrementCounter),
    flatMap(() => {
        return this.userService.counter()
        .pipe(
          map(movies => {
             return new counterActions.IncrementCounter();
          }));
      }
    ));
  });
```

Comment: Well it looks like infinite recursion to me. Effect listening for action `counterActions.CounterActionTypes.IncrementCounter` and dispatching the same action. Is this on purpose? Try using `@Effect({ dispatch: false })`

Answer (score 5):

You should add `dispatch: false` to your effect

```
  loadMovies$ = createEffect(() => {
    this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(counterActions.CounterActionTypes.IncrementCounter),
    flatMap(() => {
        return this.userService.counter()
        .pipe(
          map(movies => {
             return new counterActions.IncrementCounter();
          }));
      }
    )),
    { dispatch: false };
  });
```

Example from [document](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle)

```
  logActions$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      tap(action => console.log(action))
    ), { dispatch: false });
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not the first time I've seen this issue pop up, as it's an easy-to-make-and-overlook one.

That's why I added a rule for it in [ngrx-tslint-rules](https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-tslint-rules) to prevent it in the future.

Comment: is this compatiable with ngrx 7 ?

Comment: the lint rules are compatible with ngrx 7, but some might be obsolete - for example createEffect was introduced in ngrx 8

Answer (score 0):

You directly use oprator distinctUntilKeyChanged("<key_name>")

```js
loadMovies$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(counterActions.CounterActionTypes.IncrementCounter),
    distinctUntilKeyChanged("<key_name>"),
    flatMap(() => {
        return this.userService.counter()
        .pipe(
          map(movies => {
             return new counterActions.IncrementCounter();
          }));
      }
    ));
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

Because of **createEffect** function. You should remove wrapper createEffect function and just use this.actions$.pipe, instead. That will fix your issue. I already did and now it works okay.

```
loadMovies$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(counterActions.CounterActionTypes.IncrementCounter),
    flatMap(() => {
        return this.userService.counter()
          .pipe(
              map(movies => {
                  return new counterActions.IncrementCounter();
              })
          );
    })
);
```